# Sending EMR Logs to CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Is there a way to send EMR logs to CloudWatch instead of S3. We would like to have all our services logs in one location. Seems like the only thing you can do is set up alarms for monitoring but that doesn't cover logging.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/UsingEMR_ViewingMetrics.html

Would I have to install CloudWatch agent on the nodes in the cluster https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html

Comment: Yes thats one approach. Another one is to have a lambda listen to s3 events, open the file do console.logger().log() of every line of the file --This is quite fast, though poormans solution

Comment: Have you found any solution ? How are you dealing it now ? We need to push all our EMR logs into cloudwatch too.

Comment: @santoshkumar I think we had issues with cloudwatch agent and because of time constraints went with using lambda listening to s3 events like Ravi mentioned. 

I believe installing cloudwatch agent on each node is a better solution if you can get it to work.

Comment: cloudwatch agent is only recommended if Step Concurrency is 1 https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/push-amazon-emr-step-logs-from-amazon-ec2-instances-to-amazon-cloudwatch-logs/ and the issue with using s3 put event trigger is that it's an "at least once" guarantee, so it could trigger 2,3,4,n times per PUT statement. This may not be a problem if logging duplication isn't an issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can install the CloudWatch agent via EMR’s bootstrap configuration, and configure it to watch log directories. It then starts to push logs to Amazon CloudWatch Logs

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the technical solution a bit more?

Comment: hi is this still current? i thought emr pushed logs automatically to cloudwatch

Comment: It doesn't send them automatically. Also, only installing the agent and attaching the policy isn't enough. I couldn't figure this out yet.

Comment: need more details here. the actual AWS documentation is not really clear - because just installing the agent doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: here is an AWS article that details the process https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/push-amazon-emr-step-logs-from-amazon-ec2-instances-to-amazon-cloudwatch-logs/ the issue we have is that it is NOT recommended to use the cloudwatch agent if you have step concurrency > 1, and in many situations it seems you would want that concurrency to be greater than 1, so that solution won't work for everyone (including me, sadly)

Answer (score 1):

You can read the logs from s3 and push them to the cloudwatch using boto3 and delete them from s3 if you do not need. In some use-cases stdout.gz log will be needed to be in the cloudwatch for monitoring purposes.

boto3 documentation on [put_log_events](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.put_log_events)

```
import boto3
import botocore.session
import logging
import time
import datetime
import gzip

def get_session(service_name):
    session = botocore.session.get_session()
    aws_access_key_id = session.get_credentials().access_key
    aws_secret_access_key = session.get_credentials().secret_key
    aws_session_token = session.get_credentials().token
    region = session.get_config_variable('region')

    return boto3.client(
        service_name = service_name,
        region_name = region,
        aws_access_key_id = aws_access_key_id,
        aws_secret_access_key = aws_secret_access_key,
        aws_session_token = aws_session_token
    )

def get_log_file(s3, bucket, key):
    log_file = None

    try:
        obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        compressed_body = obj['Body'].read()
        log_file = gzip.decompress(compressed_body)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error reading from bucket : {e}")
        raise

    return log_file

def create_log_events(logs, batch_size):
    log_event_batch = []
    log_event_batch_collection = []

    try:
        for line in logs.splitlines():
            log_event = {'timestamp': int(round(time.time() * 1000)), 'message':line.decode('utf-8')}
        
            if len(log_event_batch) < batch_size:
                log_event_batch.append(log_event)
            else:
                log_event_batch_collection.append(log_event_batch)
                log_event_batch = []
                log_event_batch.append(log_event)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error creating log events : {e}")
        raise       

    log_event_batch_collection.append(log_event_batch)

    return log_event_batch_collection

def create_log_stream_and_push_log_events(logs, log_group, log_stream, log_event_batch_collection, delay):
    response = logs.create_log_stream(logGroupName=log_group, logStreamName=log_stream)
    seq_token = None

    try:
        for log_event_batch in log_event_batch_collection:
            log_event = {
                'logGroupName': log_group,
                'logStreamName': log_stream,
                'logEvents': log_event_batch
            }

            if seq_token:
                log_event['sequenceToken'] = seq_token

            response = logs.put_log_events(**log_event)
            seq_token = response['nextSequenceToken']
            time.sleep(delay)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error pushing log events : {e}")
        raise
```

The caller function

```
def main():
    s3 = get_session('s3')
    logs = get_session('logs')

    BUCKET_NAME = 'Your_Bucket_Name'
    KEY = 'logs/emr/Path_To_Log/stdout.gz'
    BATCH_SIZE = 10000         #According to boto3 docs
    PUSH_DELAY = 0.2           #According to boto3 docs 
    LOG_GROUP='test_log_group' #Destination log group
    LOG_STREAM='{}-{}'.format(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),'logstream.log')

    log_file = get_log_file(s3, BUCKET_NAME, KEY)
    log_event_batch_collection = create_log_events(log_file, BATCH_SIZE)
    create_log_stream_and_push_log_events(logs, LOG_GROUP, LOG_STREAM, log_event_batch_collection, PUSH_DELAY)
```