# AWS EMR - CloudWatch Agent required to be installed via bootstapping or not?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-emr

Quote from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/UsingEMR_ViewingMetrics.html:

> Metrics are updated every five minutes and automatically collected and
> pushed to CloudWatch for every Amazon EMR cluster. This interval is
> not configurable. There is no charge for the Amazon EMR metrics
> reported in CloudWatch. Metrics are archived for two weeks, after
> which the data is discarded.

This SO answer [Sending EMR Logs to CloudWatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59147344/sending-emr-logs-to-cloudwatch) implies an installation, but the question is 2 years old now.

So, do we need to install the CloudWatch Agent on EMR? My view is yes. Next week I will be trying it out, but a look ahead would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to. See april '20 guide where it states this.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-custom-metrics-cloudwatch/

Added the answer as it is hard to find.

Comment: my only point of confusion is that in an AWS example, it says that using cloudwatch is only recommended if you set step concurrency to 1