# AWS EMR - Using Cloudwatch Agent with step concurrency > 1

Tags: multiprocessing, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-emr, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

We are currently trying to take our EMR cluster logs and store them in Cloudwatch. I found [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/push-amazon-emr-step-logs-from-amazon-ec2-instances-to-amazon-cloudwatch-logs/) solution written by AWS where you basically just install the Cloudwatch Agent in the bootstrap step, but it goes out of it's way to give the following warning:

> The solution presented in this post is based on a specific configuration where the EMR step concurrency level is set to 1. This means that only one step is run at a time on the cluster. It’s important to note that if the EMR step concurrency level is set to a value greater than 1, the solution may not work as expected. We highly recommend verifying your EMR step concurrency configuration before implementing the solution presented in this post.

So it *seems* like you definitely should not be using the Cloudwatch Agent if your step concurrency is greater than 1, though the reason is never explained. I would like to know if the issues are just things like log duplication, or if it's something like CW Agent getting backed up and becoming a resource hog which eventually could even disrupt running jobs.

But I can't say for sure if it's really detrimental because if this is intermittent, it will be hard to find/replicate issues. I see SO articles like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67921937/aws-emr-cloudwatch-agent-required-to-be-installed-via-bootstapping-or-not) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59147344/sending-emr-logs-to-cloudwatch) which just talk about getting the Agent installed and never mention anything related to step concurrency considerations.

Erring on the side of caution makes me think that it would be safer to spin up a lambda w/ s3 trigger to just process the s3 data as it's stored by the EMR cluster, but clearly Cloudwatch Agent would be the simpler/more eloquent solution. If I better understood the potential issues of using Cloudwatch Agent w/ step concurrency > 1 I could weight the pro's and con's of it against my current needs.

Can anyone elaborate/link to documentation that better explains why Cloudwatch Agent should not be used if step concurrency is greater than 1?

Comment: Seems like there not much public information about that. I would contact AWS EMR support.